# vim: changing variable value line by line

Tags: vim

Lets say I typed the following

`a + 1 =b and a+1=c`

I need 2 more expressions like that but I want to increase the value of 1 to 3, so I copy pasted the expression above 2 more times and manually increased 1 so now my file looks like so

```
a + 1 =b and a+1=c
a + 2 =b and a+2=c
a + 3 =b and a+3=c
```

Is there a way to automate this? Kinda like search and replace, except I have to search for expression not character, because `1` is written is other expressions I don't want to change. and I want to change the value of 1 per line. Each expression is on a new line.

Comment: Also check out [vi.se], our sister site dedicated to Vim!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides using a macro you could also use find and replace

```
yy2p
:%s/\v\d+/\=line('.')/g
```

- `yy2p` yanks the line and past it two times
- `:%s` tarts a search and replace
- `\v\d+` searches for all numeric characters
- `\=line('.')` evaluates the line function as replacement for all matches

yet another option is

```
:pu! =map(range(1,3), 'printf(''a + %d =b and a+%d=c'', v:val, v:val)')
```

hard to remember but you don't have to yank, search or macro anything. Starting from an empty buffer, you get the entire enchilada in one command.

Comment: Thanks but honestly, I can blindly apply your macro or the search and replace solution but I can't get the map solution commited to my memory.

Comment: map solution is really neat!

Answer (score 4):

Vim has a way to increment a number automatically: [`<c-a>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#CTRL-A) (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>) in normal mode.

So, using a macro, it is fairly easy to construct an increasing sequence of numbers in Vim. Start at the line containing `a+ 1 =b and a+1=c` and:

```
qq
Yp^Aw^A
q
```

The `^A` stands for pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>. Then use `@q` to repeat the macro. So `4@q` would produce:

```
a + 1 =b and a+1=c
a + 2 =b and a+2=c
a + 3 =b and a+3=c
a + 4 =b and a+4=c
a + 5 =b and a+5=c
```

- `qq` starts the macro ([`q`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#complex-repeat)) saving in the register `q`.
- [`Y`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#Y) yanks the current line (linewise)
- `p` pastes and you end up at the beginning of the next (formerly current) line.
- `<c-a>` you increment the first number in the line (and the cursor moves to it)
- so you move to the next word and increment again (`w<c-a>`), this time affecting the second number.

Answer (score 2):

Many vim distributions came with builtin Perl support.

If it is your case, you can:

```
:perldo s/a\+1=b and a\+1=c/sprintf('a+%d=b and a+%d=c',++$aux,$aux)/e
```

(I probably changed the spaces in the example...)